# Rails model nested forms, how to create foreign key in 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, chartkick

I am trying to do a webpage for my project at school where a user can list out the stocks that he or she has and can check the weekly prices ( I know, not the best frequency of updates)

I have already managed to get `chartkick` and `charjs` to sort of work in my rails application, but I realised am missing something. I tried to map out my models to display the price changes.

Currently I have following models:

User

```
has_many :investment_stocks
has_many :investment_price
```

Investment_stock

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :investment_price 
belongs_to :advisor
```

Investment_price

```
has_many :investment_stocks
has_many :users, through: :investment_stocks
```

Migration

Investment_price

```
t.string :name
t.string :price
t.date :date
```

My idea is to manually change the `investment_price.price` for each of the stocks that can be referenced and displayed on the charts. But with a user having many stocks, I am wondering if my tables need something else as the way `chartkick` and `chartjs` works is that I seem to need 3 variables to be displayed on the chart but yet i always seem to be able to work around 2 only

Edited

So now I have the following

User model

```
has_many :investment_stocks
has_many :investment_prices
```

Investment_stock model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :investment_prices, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :investment_prices
```

Investment_price model

```
belongs_to :investment_stock, optional: true
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

But I am having difficulty in adding in a nested form to create on investment_stock and investment_price tables a user_id

investment_stocks controller

```
def new
@investment_stock = InvestmentStock.new
@investment_stock.investment_prices.build
end

def create
@investment_stock= InvestmentStock.new(investment_stock_params)
@investment_stock["user_id"]= current_user.id
```

How do I make it such that the user_id appears on both the stock and price tables?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think that you can try it :
Investment_price model-> belongs_to :investment_stocks, belongs_to :user .
the stocks have the price, the user have the stocks and prices.

Comment: Please add a valuable link to make this answer more useful